# C# Select Directory, Default Directory

Tags: c#, download, path, ftp, default

I'm very new to C#, I've done some Batch files and some stuff for a game called Arma 3 which uses SQF and C++. So please forgive my ignorance, I'm trying to learn.

I've recently written this code using a GUI rather than a console app. for educational purposes. it downloads form my FTP server and list the directory contents. However, When I Download the file, it says it downloads and it doesn't show up anywhere on my PC. The FTP server connects and even says it transferred properly.

How do I get a "Select Directory"  option to show up? or even a default path?

I've tried a few things and have gotten hung up. 
`using System.IO;` & `using System.Windows;` creates an error of "`"Path"` is ambiguous"

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;


namespace Downloader
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DLBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/test.txt");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test123");

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            MessageBox.Show("Download Complete", response.StatusDescription);
        }

        private void CNTBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test123");

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually **doing** anything with the response you get.  You get the response object, but you never call response.GetResponseStream() to actually get a stream, nor do you ever open a file to write to.

You'd need something like this (just writing off the top of my head, haven't tested):

```
using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(@"C:\outputfile.txt")) // or whatever
using (Stream inStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    inStream.CopyTo(outStream);  // Could also await instream.CopyToAsync() instead
}
```

If you want to prompt for a path to save to, you should look into the [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) class.